# How to do manual calculation based on distance transform obtain in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, transform, distance

***Euclidean* is distance transform from *a*** . I am using `Euclidean = bwdist(a,'euclidean');`
Based on this, may i know how the calculation works? from/to what point MATLAB calculate to get the Euclidean based on MATLAB? 
From formula , sqrt[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2], which means we need 2 points. How do MATLAB calculation for each pixel? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following link explains about the function quite directly.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html

> `D = bwdist(BW)` computes the Euclidean distance transform of the binary image BW. For each pixel in BW, the distance transform assigns a number that is the distance between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel of BW.

for your first point a(1,1), the nearest point is a(2,2), so the distance is sqrt(2).

for a(1,2), the nearest non-zero is a(2,2) too, so the distance is sqrt(1) = 1.

for a(2,2), the nearest non-zero is it self, so the distance is sqrt(0) = 0.

Good luck.

Comment: Is it apply on cityblock and chessboard too?

Comment: See "Compare 2-D Distance Transforms for Supported Distance Methods" in the same link [1](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html).   Don't know how to use comments formatting.